# C++ invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++

I wonder what happen here ?? Please advice

I'm not familiar with c++ can't I do like this ?

```
  char result = (msg[0] == 0) ? "OFF" : "ON";
  printf("A/C is " + result + "\n");
```

Comment: Nope, and the compiler told you so.  And if this is C++ you'll likely not be using `printf`.

Comment: `char`s hold `char` values. "OFF" and "ON" are not `char` values.

Comment: Code is C, tag is C++. This question is having something of an identity crisis.

Comment: Arduino is C++ ? I'm coding it

Comment: @macfij: It's C++ as well, minus the error, but that's also an error in C.

Comment: @macfij: The error is from a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. If it was a C compiler, the error would be of merging two `char *` (that are not const!)

Comment: Thank you so much any way, I end with David Grayson solution.

Comment: Thank you for being one of an apparent minority of people who accepts answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you cannot.  Try this:

```
const char * result = (msg[0] == 0) ? "OFF" : "ON";
printf("A/C is %s\n", result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
printf("A/C is %s\n", result);
```

Your `result` is actually declared with the wrong type; it should be `char const *`.

Even better (as mentioned in Ed's comment), you shouldn't be using `printf` for this. Do this instead:

```
std::cout << "A/C is " << result << "\n";
```

Comment: @EdS. I haven't missed anything: I commented that it should be `char const *`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, apparently I skipped that entire line.

Comment: I can't use in arduino std::cout it said  'cout' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @JongzPuangput Put `#include <iostream>` at the top of your program.

Comment: It appears that the arduino compiler is missing a significant part of the standard library? http://academic.cleardefinition.com/2012/09/21/using-c-on-the-arduino-a-mainstream-c-standard-library-port-for-the-avr/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using `streams`.

```
std::cout << "A/C is " << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: Prefer to output `"\n"` or `'\n'`, not `std::endl`. See [_The little `endl` that couldn't_](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/novdec95.pdf) for more information.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young That depends entirely on the sort of output the OP wants, maybe this is debug info and then it makes sense to flush with every write ... ?

Comment: Actually, the OP was using `printf`, which never flushes by default. So it's somewhat unlikely for them to have a change of heart here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't simply use the addition operation to concatenate C-style strings, second of all you should be using `std::cout` for output:

```
std::cout << "A/C is " << result << '\n';
```

If you want to concatenate strings, at least one string have to be a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) object.